# How can I add a method to a ruby class that behaves like a hash using a module mixin?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Suppose I want to define a method name(:key) using the Ruby Module Mixin metaprogramming spell (creating my own little DSL)

```
module MyDsl

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def mymethod(name)

      # name("key") 
      method_name = "#{name}".to_sym
      define_method(method_name) do |arg|
         # ...
      end

    end
  end

end
```

How can I define the methods

```
name[:key]
name[:key]=val
name[:key]+=3
name[:key]++
```

and so on

What is the syntax for the Ruby  define_method(method_name)  to allow specifying the [] array / hash access and to set values, increment values, and so on?

Comment: As a note, Ruby does not have a `++` operator.

Comment: "What is the syntax for the Ruby define_method(method_name)"? Try `ri Module#define_method` from the command-line.

Answer (score 1):

Your method `name` must return an object that has the methods `[]` and `[]=` defined. The `+=` is just a shortcut, and there is no `++` in Ruby.

If you need most of the methods of `Hash` to be available, either use a Hash or look into subclassing [`DelegateClass(Hash)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Object.html#method-i-DelegateClass) or [`SimpleDelegator`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html)